# What code coverage annotation to use in PhpUnit when a test inherits from an abstract test that tests an abstract class?

Tags: inheritance, annotations, phpunit, abstract-class, code-coverage

Say I have those classes:

```
abstract class A;
class X extends A;
class Y extends A;
```

Say I have those tests:

```
abstract class ATest extends TestCase;
class XTest extends ATest;
class YTest extends ATest;
```

With this, I ensure that `X` and `Y` do not "break/loose" the expected behaviour of the base class `A` at the same time that I don't have to repeat tests for common things (they are factored out in the `ATest`).

If `XTest` or `YTest` overwrite a method of `ATest` most probably they will call the `parent::whatever()` (or not, depending on the behaviour) but there are methods in `ATest` that probably won't be overwritten and they will be called just as tests belonging to `XTest` or `YTest` when invoked.

Okey, up to here, all right.

If I set those coverage annotations:

```
/** @covers \My\Nice\Project\A */
abstract class ATest extends TestCase

/** @covers \My\Nice\Project\X */
class XTest extends ATest

/** @covers \My\Nice\Project\Y */
class YTest extends ATest
```

then when I run the phpunit runner with --coverage-html I get `X` and `Y` covered 100% but `A` covered 0%.

The reason is that `ATest` is never really invoked by the test runner as it is an abstract test class (the runner cannot instantiate it), and when running its tests, it is in fact called via the `XTest` and `YTest` extensions.

## Problem

I want to have `class A` covered while I don't want to leave the tests without the `@covers` annotation.

## Possible solution

```
abstract class ATest extends TestCase

/**
  * @covers \My\Nice\Project\X
  * @covers \My\Nice\Project\A
  */
class XTest extends ATest

/**
  * @covers \My\Nice\Project\Y
  * @covers \My\Nice\Project\A
  */
class YTest extends ATest
```

## Question

I feel there's a smell in there.

Is this the proper way? If not, what's the way I should tell phpunit that the `TestA` is covering `A` and have this meta-information extended as well into the `TestX` and `TestY`?

Note: Using PHPUnit 6.5.11 for this project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bad smell by covering an abstract classes. That's the way how code coverage works. There is Code, so you have to cover it.

It doesn't matter that `ATest` is also an abstract class. The class `ATest` is not a testcase. But I know what you mean. There are no annotations in PHP, it's still a comment. So there are no a part of inheritance.

Perhaps.. the bad smell comes from an inheritance problem and you should consider about composition over inheritence or strategy pattern. In my experience mostly a problem in legacy software.

Comment: Well... In this case, inheritance is the correct case, not composition. I finally opted for having XTest to cover only X, then YTest to cover only Y. And add another test: AConcreteTest which tests a class that lives not in src/ but in tests/helpers and that is a concrete implementation of A implementing exclusively the minimum needed functionality to make A to work and make AConcreteTest to test the "common parts" to X and Y. This approach makes all clean. in the `@covers` AConcreteTest is said to cover A, not AConcrete.

Comment: @XaviMontero I'm facing the same issue, but be careful with this solution, as you are not writing tests the correct way IMHO: you are covering all the possible code, but not testing that both `X` and `Y` classes can access/use `A` base class properties/methods. If during refactoring you end up (by mistake) removing `A` class inheritance from `X` or `Y` you wouldn't notice with  your tests, that's why in this cases I do always duplicates my tests for every child class and if possible refactor tests common parts into reusable helper methods.